# How do I taskset vscode-server?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, visual-studio-code-server, taskset

Often, I'm using VS Code's Remote SSH extension to develop on a remote server. This consumes some compute on the server, so I'd like to `taskset` the `vscode-server` command so that it only runs on certain cores.

I've tried (without much success) to find the exact command that the Remote SSH extension runs on the remote server.

From looking at the output of `ps`, it seems the first command is `~/.vscode-server/bin/<commit>/bin/code-server --start-server ...`, which seems to spawn several child processes.

How do I modify this command from the local machine and prefix it with `taskset -c 0`?

Comment: Also, I'm not trying to start a `tunnel` on the remote host. I just want the out of the box vscode-server to run, but only on specific cores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to put following at the beginning of `code-server` :

```
if test -z "$TASKSET_FLAG"; then
    export TASKSET_FLAG=1
    exec taskset -c 0 "$0" "$@"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

One temporary solution I've found is to use `ps` to get the PIDs of the vscode-server processes, pipe them through awk, then manually taskset them.

```
ps aux | grep vscode-server | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I {} taskset -cp <your_fav_core> {}
```